# How does Embo’s shield/hat/chakram thing come back to him after he throws it

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

He seems to use it like a chakram and a shield. Embo throws it, it hits the target, and then ends up in Embo’s hands. Is there an In-Universe reason the hat comes back?

Comment: The same way you get to Carnegie Hall

Comment: And how exactly do you do that?

Comment: It has a built-in "return to Embo" function.

Comment: @DavidW, how would it work. As far as I know, Embo isn’t force-sensitive or anything else.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPDheKeLEgk - It only seems to about 20% of the time, mostly as a result of lucky bounces. Otherwise he has to walk over and get it or have it carried to him.

Comment: @Valorum, hadn’t noticed that